# What is EPS in THREE.OrbitControl?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

In `this.update` method of `THREE.OrbitControl` have a private variable named EPS that trim the phi angle as described below:

```
// restrict phi to be betwee EPS and PI-EPS
phi = Math.max( EPS, Math.min( Math.PI - EPS, phi ) );
```

What the meaning of EPS?
It is an Acronym for something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EPS`, in this case, is an acronym for the Greek letter epsilon, which is a variable name in mathematics often used to represent a small number.

Comment: hmm but what the meaning?
Why we have to trim phi with `EPS` and pi - `EPS`?

Comment: It is to prevent the polar angle from being exactly zero or exactly pi (180 degrees) -- two values where there can be instability issues in the calculations.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Indeed i think it is pi or zero the model or camera can be turn around itself producing a little flicker?

Comment: yep, that's true Luiz